# Choosing between Akka, Twitter Finagle and Vert.x pros and cons or EJBs are still enough

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, ejb, distributed

For distributed computing using java stack, how can these frameworks or libs can fits in these categories.

- documentation
- adoption
- easy to use and integrate with well widely used technologies like spring, orm and web frameworks
- fault tolerant
- security.

EJBs could replace all these new kids on the block for distributed computing, scalable and fault tolerant system architecture?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the kind of scenario you have in mind? Along the lines of what kind of work you intend to distribute?

Comment: I'm interested to work with some kinds of system communications, including messages exchanged, sockets and ssl/https connections in with a lot of asynchronous operations. And is necessary to deal with heterogeneous kind of data. Because the application has various kind of data storage, neo4j, redis and mysql. I'm studying the possibility to work with spring data to help deal with NoSQL stuff. But my doubt is to choose an architecture to deal with distributed relationships with different data sources and communications protocols. Maybe I'm looking for ESB solutions, or EJBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB 3 are designed to be easy to use and easy to integrate, there is a lot of documentation and they are the Java standard for distributed computing.

The EJB container provides the transaction management and the security based on standard specification. The container itself is provider by many companies with enterprise support or free use (IBM, JBoss, Oracle)

Your software can become fault tolerant without modification to the code is you follow the EJB specs, you can just put the servers in cluster (there are many cluster strategies) and can scale horizontally without effort is you use stateless session beans

The other frameworks/.technologies you mentioned are very valid but none can provide all these features

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a too general question. 
EJB is been used for many years now , and is widely documented, perhaps more than all the technologies you mentioned altogether, and more mature. 
You can use JAAS for authorization and authentication (when it comes to security). 
For example, I'm using the Krb5LoginModule at the [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project I'm one of its maintainers.
You can use secured HTTP when accessing the web container of the application server. 
At oVirt we're using the JBoss application server, and you can use JBoss-cluster to achieve clustering. You can use infinispan to get a scalable shared data structure (data grid) across nodes. 
We use Spring components at our application (for injection you can use [CDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ejb-3-1-175064.html)) - for LDAP queries, for working with the DB (we currently prefer Spring-JDBC over JPA due to performance reasons). 
I've been using a stack of web application that looks up beans that are injected with EntityManager and perform CRUD operations using JPA (and hibernate as the JPA provider) for several years, prior to my current working place 
I'm sure you can achieve all this using spring - for example - use a stack of spring-mvc + spring-orm. 
I don't think any of the technologies will give you a distributed system in a "magical" way, and you will still have to invest time on development, design, testing of scalability, etc..